# Prove that the function $f: \mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R^2}$ given by $f(x,y,z) = (xy+xz+yz, e^{xyz})$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, continuity

Prove that $f: \mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R^2}$ given by $f(x,y,z) = (xy+xz+yz, e^{xyz})$ is continuous.

(this was the only method I could come up with and I'm not sure if it is correct, if there any other simple methods that are better, please share them)

Attempt:

$f_1(x,y,z)= xy+xz+yz$

Since each component of $f_1$ is an elementary function defined everywhere on $\mathbb{R^2}$ we say it is continuous.

$f_2(x,y,z)$=$e^{xyz}$

$f_2$ is continuous for the same reasons as $f_1$

Comment: This depends on how much are you allowed to assume. If you're allowed to assume that polynomials, exponentials and composition and sum of those are continiuous, then it is automatic.

Comment: And doing it any other way would be a massive pain

Comment: What definition of "continuity" are you using?

Comment: @Javi I'm allowed to assume what you said. Is my obvious proof ok?

Comment: @Mathissohardlmao yes, it is